# Keybpard shortcut in Spyder to temporarily make a single pane the only pane

Tags: spyder

If I have multiple panes in the Matlab's IDE, Shift-Ctrl-M causes the one with the focus to become the only visibe pane, taking up the entire IDE window.  Pressing Shift-Ctrl-M again brings back all the other panes that were present, and the pane with the focus becomes just one pane among many again.

Is there such a shortcut key in the Spyder IDE?

There is a GUI button to do this, but I wonder if there is also a shortcut key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The shortcut for that in Spyder is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

*Note*: You can browse and modify all our available shortcuts by going to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts`

Comment: Thanks Carlos!  And I just found the Shortcuts Summary under the Help menu.  BTW, it is invoked by Meta-F1 -- is there Windows counterpart?

Comment: In Windows Meta correspond to the Windows key.

Comment: I am sad...doesn't seem to work on my system.  Windows-F1 just brings up the Help and Support panel.  Toshiba Portege R930, Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.  My Spyder was installed as part of Anaconda.  Unfortunately, I can't experiment much with installation, as I don't have administrator privileges.